# How to make code navigation work in Visual Studio Code like it used to?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code

I have problems in getting (former?) code navigation work in Visual Studio Code properly. For example, `Ctrl` + `click` on an error link, in the Visual Studio Code native powershell terminal, does not direct me to the actual file and problem code.

[image]

Instead, I get something pretty useless highlighted in a box above. I don't want that!

Of course I have googled for this issue, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything which really helped me. Many sources out there talks about possible erroneous settings in `settings.json`. Here is what's in mine:

```
{
    "debug.javascript.warnOnLongPrediction": false,
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false
}
```

**Update 1:**
I moved my vue project (`timerge-frontend`) to a location with no spaces in its name according to a tip from mr @daniel-b, `C:\timerge-frontend`. Then I provoked a new error by removing a referenced component. I got my expected error, but when I `Ctrl` + `click` on it, the behavior was unfortunately exactly the same as before.

**Update 2**
Mr @daniel-b, was right. After my update and new provokation, I didn't read the error message good enough. It shouldn't be possible to navigate to a removed component... :-)

**Question:** Which settings do I need to have to let `Ctrl` + `click` on an error link (for example) navigate me directly to the problem code?

Comment: Does your Windows user name (or folder, that’s what really matters) perhaps have a space in it? The link underline looks suspicious.

Comment: Yes, it (the folder) has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code cannot deal with whitespaces in the path. You can see from the underline that it doesn’t pick up the full path. There’s nothing you can do about this either.

There are two ways forward:

- Don’t work in paths that have spaces in them
- Make sure your tools only output relative paths (this may be a valid issue to raise with `vue-cli` if that’s what you’re using)